# ArcMap 10.1 point snap: Unable to snap to a point please help!

Tags: arcmap, snapping

Very basic question sorry, missing some fundamentals.

Outline: 
I have 4 points as a .shp also converted to .lyr that I brought in as a x/y table and converted.   I want to create a polygon as a separate shapefile that is defined by the 4 points - I have done this using the other option of entering the actual coordinates of the point in edit menu.

Current status:
I have added these files to to my geodatabase also in my project folder, tried many different things to make the snap to point work for these imported x,y points.  If I create a polygon and save as a shapefile, I can snap to that no problem.  The problems seems to be just with these imported x/y points.

Sure I a missing something very basic, any help would be much appreciated I am going round in circles.

Answer (score 2):

To reiterate my comment on **dmahr**'s answer, I think this will solve your problems:

> You probably need to turn the XY event layer into a proper point feature class/shapefile. You should be able to do so by right-clicking on them in the table of contents and going to Data -> Export Data...

Answer (score 0):

To enable the desired snapping in edit sessions, you need to turn on the snapping toolbar, check "Use snapping" toggle in the dropdown, and toggle the "Point Snapping" button, as shown below:

[image: Snapping toolbar]

[image: Toggle these]

Comment: thanks dmahr, I did notice that snapping toolbar.  The problem is I have all these toggled 'on' and I can snap to a polygon sketch I have created.  I cannot however snap to the points that I brought in from an x/y table.  its almost like it is non-selectable

Comment: You probably need to turn the XY points into a proper point feature class/shapefile. You should be able to do so by right-clicking on them in the table of contents and going to Data -> Export.

Comment: @nmpeterson - you should post your comment as an answer.  Making the 'Add XY event layer' a permanent feature is the cause of the snapping problems the OP is experiencing.